# How to open PayPal not in a modal window, but in a new tab in React

Tags: reactjs, paypal, tabs, modal-dialog, paypal-sandbox

I used react-paypal-express-checkout. But in this plugin I did not find any possibility to add target='_blank'.

```
import React from 'react';
import PaypalExpressBtn from "react-paypal-express-checkout";

const PayPalButton = ({ value }) => {
 ...

    return (
      <PaypalExpressBtn
        style={style}
        client={client}
        currency='USD'
        total={value}
        onSuccess={onSuccess}
        onCancel={onCancel}
        onError={onError}
      />

    );
}

export default PayPalButton;
```

Is there any advice?